# Prevent site from "folding" when browser window shrunk

Tags: html

I have a site with a horizontal ul/li of buttons across the top.  If someone shrinks the window, the buttons fold down into two rows.  It's kind of ugly.

I threw up an example:

http://www.redolog.com

I'm wondering if there is a layout directive that says "look, you have to be at least 800 wide and otherwise, you'll have to scroll" and create a scrollbar at the bottom instead of "folding" the site?

Does that make sense?  Or am I being dumb?  :-)

Comment: You may have legitimate reasons for doing this, however I would like to note for general readers that horizontal scrolling is generally disliked and discouraged. If you can find a way to have elements float _without_ looking ugly, that may be a more ideal solution.

Answer (score 5):

Put this in your css:

```
body { min-width: 800px }
```